# Validating string size in forms

Tags: php, validation, symfony, doctrine-orm

While setting up a doctrine entity to be used alongside a Symfony form, I want to validate that the given string size is not going to exceed the column size of the database. Notice I use the word size and not length.

Symfony ships with a number of validation constraints, in particular the [Length Constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Length.html#charset). However, looking at it's documentation

> The charset to be used when computing value's length. The
>   grapheme_strlen PHP function is used if available. If not, the
>   mb_strlen PHP function is used if available. If neither are available,
>   the strlen PHP function is used.

It uses `grapheme_strlen` or `mb_strlen` which return the visual length of the string and NOT the actual size. When dealing with non ASCII strings, the actual size is a factor. For example most Asian languages use 3 bytes for each character.

The [doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-column) states nothing about the `@Column(length)` annotation which leads me to believe it's a byte count. So, If I declare a column of length 64 and a constraint of max-size 64, there is going to be a problem.

Now, I could use a [Callback Constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) or even create a custom constraint. But, is there a better way? How should strings received from form fields have their size validated before being persisted to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the documentation does mention the order of function that will be chosen between.

However, that got me thinking and I went to see it for myself in a source code. There's no trace of such thing. I would tend to believe that they wanted to say that these functions will be used to determine the charset, however, no such thing exists in the source code either. I think it's some kind of typo, copy/paste error.

[**Here**](https://github.com/symfony/validator/blob/master/Constraints/LengthValidator.php), take a look:

```
$stringValue = (string) $value;
if ('UTF8' === $charset = strtoupper($constraint->charset)) {
    $charset = 'UTF-8'; // iconv on Windows requires "UTF-8" instead of "UTF8"
}

$length = @iconv_strlen($stringValue, $charset);
$invalidCharset = false === $length;
```

In fact, they use [`iconv_strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-strlen.php) to determine the right length. I think it's safe to assume your validation will do just fine.

As for the `@Column` `length` parameter, that one is not intended for validation, but to schema creation/migration processes. As such, it should not be regarded as a safeguard for a validation processes.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: I think you missed the point of my question. Even with `iconv_strlen`, I'm not getting the byte count of the string, but the database column IS defined by byte size. There is a miss match when validating the string length returned from a form and what is to be added to the database.